# Rails 4 nested form with has_many, through and multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many-through, has-many, multiple-select

I have a problem with nested form and has_many relation. Bussiness case: there are laboratories and their suppliers. Suppliers can be shared between labs.

**Models**

```
class Lab < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lab_suppliers
  has_many :suppliers, through: :lab_suppliers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lab_suppliers
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lab_suppliers
  has_many :labs, through: :lab_suppliers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lab_suppliers
end

class LabSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lab
  belongs_to :supplier

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lab
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplier
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@lab) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class"field">
    <%= fields_for :lab_suppliers do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.label :supplier_id %><br>
      <%= ff.collection_select :supplier_id, Supplier.all, :id, :name,  {include_blank: true}, {:multiple => true, :class=>""} %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class LabsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lab, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /labs/new
  def new
    @lab = Lab.new
    @lab.lab_suppliers.build
  end

  # POST /labs
  # POST /labs.json
  def create
    #raise params.inspect

    @lab = Lab.new(lab_params)

    @lab_supplier = @lab.lab_suppliers.new(params[:lab_suppliers])
    @lab_supplier.save
    @lab.save


    private

    def lab_params
      params.require(:lab).permit(:code, :name, lab_suppliers_attributes: [])
    end
end
```

Result of the inspect on params after submitting form:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "lab"=>{"code"=>"L01",
 "name"=>"xxx"},
 "lab_suppliers"=>{"supplier_id"=>["",
 "1",
 "3"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Lab"}
```

While submitting form I receive ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
on the line:

```
@lab_supplier = @lab.lab_suppliers.new(params[:lab_suppliers])
```

What am i missing to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to explicitly tell `lab_params` which attributes from `lab_suppliers` you need to pass like:

```
params.require(:lab).permit(:code, :name, lab_suppliers_attributes: [:supplier_id])
```

Try it and let me know.

Comment: Nope, I have tried that and still I receive the same error. I think problem is that lab_suppliers params are not nested in the lab_params

Comment: in here: <%= fields_for :lab_suppliers do |ff| %>  try to do <%= f.fields_for :lab_suppliers do |ff| %>      so, put the f

Comment: You were right. Changing to f.fields_for made the lab_suppliers form values to be nested inside lab_params

Answer (score 0):

Link to other post that helped me to find the working solution: 
[[Rails nested form with multiple entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576277/rails-nested-form-with-multiple-entries][1])

Below I provide the working solution showing how to pass values from the multiple select as nested attributes and insert them to the db.

**Models**

```
class Lab < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :lab_suppliers#, :foreign_key => 'lab_id', dependent: :destroy
   has_many :suppliers, through: :lab_suppliers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :lab_suppliers, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lab_suppliers
  has_many :labs, through: :lab_suppliers
end

class LabSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lab
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

Comment: 
accepts_nested_attributes_for is put only on has_many/has_one side. No need to put it on belongs_to side

**Form (Lab)**

```
<%= form_for(@lab) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
    <div class"field">
<%= f.fields_for :lab_suppliers do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :supplier_id %><br>
  <%= ff.collection_select :supplier_id, Supplier.all, :id, :name,  {include_blank: true}, {:multiple => true, :class=>""} %>
<% end %>
```

<%= f.submit %><% end %>

**Controller**

Comment:
There is no need to permit any additional params in supplier or lab_suppliers controllers

```
class LabsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lab, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
  @lab = Lab.new
  @lab.lab_suppliers.build
end


def create
   @lab = Lab.new(lab_params)

@startcount=1   #start counting from 1 because the first element in the array of nested params is always null
@lab.lab_suppliers.each do |m|
  #raise lab_params[:lab_suppliers_attributes]["0"][:supplier_id][@startcount].inspect
  m.supplier_id = lab_params[:lab_suppliers_attributes]["0"][:supplier_id][@startcount]
  @startcount +=1
end 

respond_to do |format|
  if @lab.save
    lab_params[:lab_suppliers_attributes]["0"][:supplier_id].drop(@startcount).each do |m|
      @lab.lab_suppliers.build(:supplier_id => lab_params[:lab_suppliers_attributes]["0"][:supplier_id][@startcount]).save
      @startcount += 1
    end
    format.html { redirect_to labs_path, notice: 'Lab was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lab }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @lab.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


    private

def lab_params
  params.require(:lab).permit(:name, :code, lab_suppliers_attributes: [supplier_id: [] ])
end
end
```

Comment: supplier_id: [] in the lab_suppliers_attributes permitts array of values from the multiple dropdown to be passed