# Unpermitted parameter for join table via multiple select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms, multiple-select

I'm running into an error when nesting parameters in Rails 5: `Unpermitted parameter: specialties`

I have an Expertise model:

```
class Expertise < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :buckets, through: :specialties
    has_many :specialties   
end
```

A Bucket model:

```
class Bucket < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :expertises, through: :specialties
    has_many :specialties
end
```

And a Specialty model:

```
class Specialty < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :expertise
    belongs_to :bucket
end
```

I'm trying to allow the User to edit his or her Expertises and adjust the Specialties associated with them. The `@buckets` are passed in from the controller, and the form currently looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(expertise) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :specialties do |s| %>
        <%= s.collection_select :bucket_ids, @buckets, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: "input" } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I based the form on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590253/4163426).

Here's the relevant snippet from the ExpertisesController:

```
def expertise_params
    params.require(:expertise).permit(:user_id, :name, :rating, :description, specialties_attributes: [:id, :expertise_id, :bucket_id, :_destroy, bucket_ids: []])
end
```

And here are the parameters that are being passed in:

```
Parameters: {"expertise"=>{"specialties"=>{"bucket_ids"=>["", "1"]}, "description"=>""}, "id"=>"97"}
```

Specialties should be an array, right? I'm not sure how to do that.

The aim is to easily enable the User to select from the available Buckets (`@buckets`) to toggle his or her Expertise Specialties on or off. So let's say there are 5 Buckets available, the User would only be able to toggle on/off 5 possible Specialties for that Expertise.

Comment: Do you already tried to switch `specialties_attributes` to `specialties`?

Comment: Can you paste the log output?

Comment: @ThiagoUruray, I tried that, but it threw an error: "Specialty expected, got Array"

Comment: @JCorcuera, Added the parameters from the log, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @Andrew I guess you could try `accepts_nested_attributes_for :specialties` on expertise model

Comment: @ThiagoUruray, Thank you for your help. When I try that, the nested `fields_for` form doesn't return any `specialties` and so the HTML element is empty. Then, when I try to use `@expertise.specialties.build`, I get `undefined method bucket_ids` for Specialty because `bucket_ids` isn't actually an attribute, but `bucket_id` is. Worth keeping in mind that the User needs to be able to toggle multiple Specialties, each of which is tied to a Bucket (via a `bucket_id`), and from what I've ready I'm supposed to use `bucket_ids` (the plural) there.

Comment: Oh, I see! When you try to build with `expertise_params` rails tries to build a new Expertise Object assigning the params as attributes of expertise. You can remove bucket_ids from expertise_params and process it after the build

Comment: @ThiagoUruray, What exactly would that look like? Would you mind expanding on that in an answer? I'm having a hard time putting that together.

Comment: @Andrew check if my answer matches your question, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147118/discussion-between-andrew-and-thiago-ururay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: specialties

You didn't set up `accept_nested_attributes_for` which spits out with that error

```
class Expertise < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :specialties
  has_many :buckets, through: :specialties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :specialties
end
```

> When I try that, the nested fields_for form doesn't return any
>   specialties and so the HTML element is empty. Then, when I try to use
>   @expertise.specialties.build, I get undefined method bucket_ids for
>   Specialty because bucket_ids isn't actually an attribute, but
>   bucket_id is. Worth keeping in mind that the User needs to be able to
>   toggle multiple Specialties, each of which is tied to a Bucket (via a
>   bucket_id), and from what I've ready I'm supposed to use bucket_ids
>   (the plural) there

<s>You don't need to have *plural form(**_ids**)* just because to accept multiple values. Just keep `bucket_id` to accept multiple values. And don't forget to build the associated model in the controller</s>

<s>def new
      @expertise = Expertise.new
      @expertise.specialties.build
    end</s>

Change `bucket_ids` to `bucket_id` in the form

<s><%= s.collection_select :bucket_id, @buckets, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: "input" } %></s>

<s>And finally, `expertise_params` should be</s>

```
def expertise_params
  params.require(:expertise).permit(:user_id, :name, :rating, :description, specialties_attributes: [:id, :expertise_id, :_destroy, bucket_id: []])
end
```

***Update:***

Ok after some research, it looks like it should be `bucket_ids`, but the `bucket_ids` should be *allowed as attribute for `expertise`*. Check this [*post*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826407/rails-3-multiple-select-with-has-many-through-associations) and tweak your `form` and `expertise_params` accordingly. You won't be needing `accept_nested_attributes_for` too!

Comment: Thank you for your help. This got me closer, but still not quite there. I can now save the Specialty, but it doesn't have a Bucket associated with it. Here are the params, if they're helpful: `"expertise"=>{"specialties_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"bucket_id"=>["", "1"]}}}`

Comment: @Andrew Can you post that `INSERT` call that you got in the server log?

Comment: Here you go: `INSERT INTO "specialties" ("expertise_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["expertise_id", 97], ["created_at", 2017-06-20 16:04:12 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-20 16:04:12 UTC]]`

Comment: @Andrew Ok after some research, it looks like it should be `bucket_ids`, but the `bucket_ids` should be allowed as attribute for `expertise`. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826407/rails-3-multiple-select-with-has-many-through-associations and tweak your `form` and `expertise_params`. You won't be needing `accept_nested_attributes_for` too

Comment: @Andrew Glad it worked :) I included an update in answer stating the same, so you can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

The situation: Expertise has_many Buckets through Specialties and you want to update some bucket status of a specific expertise. So you can do this:

```
class ExpertisesController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    @expertise = Expertise.find params[:id]
    bucket_ids = params[:expertise][:specialties][:bucket_ids]
    @expertise.specialties.where(id: bucket_ids).update(status: :on)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd like to create and delete Specialty objects depending on which corresponding Buckets are selected, not update a property on a Specialty object.